# Как лучше по-русски сказать "production" (по отношению к IT)?

Tags: заимствования, грамотная-речь, компьютеры

Как правильно сказать по-русски "production server", "production code", "production mode" и т.д.?

Единственный вариант, который приходит в голову, это "производство". Но, например, "`сборку из разработки загрузили на тестировочный сервер, а потом и на производственный сервер`" звучит странновато.

Comment: Мне кажется, эта тема (в широком смысле) интересная. Я как раз сейчас сижу над английским техническим текстом (генетика, статистика, программирование) и мучаюсь практически над каждой фразой из-за обилия терминов и научного жаргона.  
Хотелось бы иметь возможность посоветоваться по поводу переводов.

Comment: "самому изобретать лексикон - не лучшая идея" -> кто-то же должен первым ввести слово в употребление (в том числе то, которое потом станет литературным).

Comment: Но Черная Королева не дала ей договорить.  

- Никогда не заговаривай первой! - сказала она строго.  
- Но, если бы все соблюдали это правило, - возразила Алиса, всегда готовая немного поспорить, - и, если бы никто не заговаривал первым и только бы _ждал_, пока с ним заговорят, а те бы тоже ждали, тогда бы никто вообще ничего не говорил.

Comment: Предлагаю вариант "сборку из разработки загрузили на сервер для тестирования, а потом и на рабочий сервер"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут достаточно важный момент заключается в том, кому сказать и при каких обстоятельствах. На мой взгляд, сленговые "девелопмент" и "продакшн" очень часто являются наилучшей формой (в разговорной речи). По крайней мере, они не вызывают затруднений в понимании у тех, кому это действительно нужно.

"сборку из разработки загрузили на тестировочный сервер, а потом и на производственный сервер"

я бы перевел как

"разрабатываемую сборку развернули сначала на тестовом сервере, а затем и на "боевом" сервере"

В зависимости от аудитории, "боевой" можно заменить на "рабочий", я думаю.

А вообще, [вот](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/18072/) достаточно интересное обсуждение на хабре.

Comment: "кому сказать и при каких обстоятельствах" -> Не люблю такие варианты. Хочется чтобы было одновременно правильно, красиво и понятно.

Comment: > По крайней мере, они не вызывают затруднений в понимании у тех, кому это действительно нужно.  

Не у всех, кому нужно! Только у тех, кто уже давно "в теме". А как трудно начинающим, особенно тем, кто учится самостоятельно!  Лично столкнулась с этой проблемой (изучаю сейчас программирование на языке R, а там вся справочная система на английском. Тихий ужас!)

Answer (score 2):

Production - эксплуатация. Production server - эксплуатационный сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Простой гугловский переводчик дает "рабочий сервер", "производство код", "рабочем режиме". Со вторым случаем не справился ;-))

Answer (score 1):

[@gecube](/users/972/gecube) "лучше сказать production " Это как раз худшее - это вообще отсутствие перевода. (Я как профессиональный переводчик советской школы утверждаю.) Как раз НИКТО НИЧЕГО не поймет. Тогда, по вашей логике, вообще ничего не надо переводить. Зачем? Перепишите полностью английскую фразу или весь текст по-английски. И ВСЁ ВСЕ ПОЙМУТ, кому надо. "В русском языке нет точного перевода" - это проблема скудоумия переводящего. Есть десяток методов ПЕРЕДАЧИ смысла с одного язык на другой.

Answer (score 0):

Да по-разному говорят: основной, боевой, рабочий... 
Вам для какой цели? Потому как у вас даже слово "тестировочный" вызывает вопросы. На общепринятом русском - тестовый. Про "сборку из разработки", которой "загрузили", вообще молчу.

А вообще, имхо, такие вопросы лучше на bit-code спрашивать. Не хватало ещё этот форум сделать филиалом программистских разборок (это я вам как программист программисту говорю).

Comment: "основной, боевой, рабочий" -> Что из этого наиболее официально? Что бы вы написали в документе?

Comment: `Про "сборку из разработки", которой "загрузили", вообще молчу.` -> А как лучше? Имеется в виду "development build", "uploaded/pushed".

Comment: 'такие вопросы лучше на bit-code спрашивать' -> вопрос по языку же.

Comment: Смотря что за документ. Мне не приходилось писать документов с упоминанием подобных вещей уровнем выше предприятия.  В моих случаях вполне прокатывало "рабочий" по отношению к серверу, двусмысленности не возникало. Остальные ваши примеры надо разбтрать в контексте.

Comment: > А вообще, имхо, такие вопросы лучше на bit-code спрашивать. Не хватало ещё этот форум сделать филиалом программистских разборок

Вообще-то программистские форумы были ядром Сети знаний. Так что обслуживание потребностей программистов - естественная цель Русского языка. Ведь у математиков сказано: 
> Математика - это форум, посвященный математике, с особым акцентом на компьютерные науки.
Почему бы ив Русском языке такой акцент не сделать?

Comment: Конечно, слова "тестировочный" в русском языке нет. Но, мне кажется, сочетание "тестовый сервер" - все-таки не совсем отражает смысл высказывания. Мне бы пришлось долго подумать, чтобы понять, что это значит...

Comment: > Но, мне кажется, сочетание   

Вот поэтому я и не хотел бы делать из этого форума ещё один филиал "мне кажется", коих в сети и без того предостаточно. На моей памяти не одно такое превращение хороших форумных ресурсов в никакие (самое обидное мз которых - gramota.ru). Когда все разом начинают говорить "о своем, о девичьем", все одновременно и перестают слушать.

Comment: Ну, не так уж много желающих высказаться. Для хорошего форума нужны несколько профессионалов, здесь это есть. Кстати, Вы имеете право удалять лишние комменты. Я, правда, на Математике тоже имею такое право, но практически не пользуюсь.

Comment: Я почему-то пропустил прямые вопросы, мне адресованные. Простите. Как я понимаю, актуальность отпала? 
На всякий случай: 
>"основной, боевой, рабочий" -> ...Что бы вы написали в документе?   

Скорее "основной". Но я почти не писал подобных бумаг.

>А как лучше? Имеется в виду "development build", "uploaded/pushed".  

Не знаю, право. Всё плохо. Я же не говорил, что надо переделывать, я том, что невозможно угнаться за всеми читающими. Мне такие вещи более или менее понятны, дяде Ване с вантузом - вряд ли. Нельзя дать идеальной формулировки без оглядки на аудиторию.

Answer (score 0):

Честно сказать, лучше сказать production :-) Все все поймут. Если же перевести на русский, то, во-первых, точного перевода не существует, во-вторых, самому изобретать лексикон - не лучшая идея. Всегда найдется тот, кто не поймет о чем идет речь, или кто будет считать, что лучше эту вещь назвать по-другому. Вот. Ну, и если переводите своим образом, то надо в начале технических документов делать расшифровку терминов (список определений).

Comment: Нормально ли будет смотреться, если в документе для разной аудитории все такие термины будут написаны просто по-английски, а в начале приведён <s>маленький англо-русский словарик</s> глоссарий?

Comment: Хорошо бы инициировать составление таких словариков по отдельных техническим разделам. Только вот кто может это координировать? Для меня эта проблема очень актуальная и болезненная.

Answer (score 0):

Сколько работаю всегда говорим:
Production Server - боевой сервер
Test Server - тестовый сервер